# How to convert the object property type integer to string in .net core controller?

Tags: asp.net-core

CMJobProgController.cs
This is the controlelr class

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var allObj = _unitOfWork.cmJobProg.GetALL(j => j.AssignFrom == "JENNYCMS" || j.AssignTo=="JENNYCMS");
            var pubcode = _unitOfWork.pubcode.GetALL(s => s.CodeType == "JPA" || s.CodeType=="DIV" );

          
            
           foreach (CMJobProg c in allObj)
            {
                if (c.Division!=null)
                {
                    foreach(PubCode p in pubcode)
                    {                       
                        if (c.Division == p.Code1 && p.CodeType=="DIV") //this part no problem cause the type is same
                        {
                            c.Division = p.CodeDesc;
                        }
                             
                    }
                }

                if (c.JobAction != null)
                {


                    foreach (PubCode p in pubcode)
                    {
                        if (c.JobAction.Tostring() == p.Code1 && p.CodeType == "JPA") 
                        {

                            c.JobAction = p.CodeDesc; // this part will has error, cause my c.JobAction is integer and p.Code1 is string.
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
           
                                        
            return Json(new { data = allObj });
        }
```

CMJobProg.cs
This is the CMJobProg model class

```
public class CMJobProg
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(8)]
        [Display(Name = "Job Number")]
        [Column("JOB_NUMBER")]
        [JsonPropertyName("jobnumber")]
        public string JobNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Assign From")]
        [MaxLength(22)]
        [Column("ASSIGN_FROM")]
        [JsonPropertyName("assignfrom")]
        public string AssignFrom { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Assign To")]
        [MaxLength(22)]
        [Column("ASSIGN_TO")]
        [JsonPropertyName("assignto")]
        public string AssignTo { get; set; }

        [Column("DATE_ASSIGN")]
        [JsonPropertyName("dateassign")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]     
        public DateTime DateAssign { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Job Action")]
        [Range(0, 999)]
        [Column("JOB_ACTION")]
        [JsonPropertyName("jobaction")]
        public int? JobAction { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remarks")]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        [Column("REMARKS")]
        [JsonPropertyName("remarks")]
        public string Remarks { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Job Type")]
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(2)]
        [Column("TYPE")]
        [JsonPropertyName("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2)]
        [Column("DIVISION")]
        [JsonPropertyName("division")]
        public string Division { get; set; }

       
    }
```

PubCode.cs
This is the PubCode model class

```
public class PubCode
    {
        
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code Type")]
        [Column("CODE_TYPE")]
        public string CodeType { get; set; }

        
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code 1")]
        [Column("CODE_1")]
        public string Code1 { get; set; }

        
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code 2")]
        [Column("CODE_2")]
        public string Code2 { get; set; }

        
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code 3")]
        [Column("CODE_3")]
        public string Code3 { get; set; }

        
        [MaxLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Code 4")]
        [Column("CODE_4")]
        public string Code4 { get; set; }

        
        [MaxLength(15)]
        [Display(Name = "Code ACR")]
        [Column("CODE_ACR")]
        public string CodeACR { get; set; }

        
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Code Description")]
        [Column("CODE_DESC")]
        public string CodeDesc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Anyone could help me please? How to change the object property type integer to string for above condition?

The above CMJobProg.cs and Pubcode.cs are the model class that the data will reteive from the database.

Comment: What problem when convert toString for `if` condiftion 
c.JobAction.ToString();

Comment: c.JobAction is an integer type, i want to assign p.CodeDesc which is string type into it. I had edit it. Should be c.JobAction = p.CodeDesc; will have problem.

Comment: So you want to `cast type` something like this `(int)p.CodeDesc`

Comment: no. I want to change the c.JobAction to string. and the c.JobAction type is int? in model class.

Comment: Do you mean you want to directly convert the int to string type when reading from database?

Comment: I solved it already. I just change the model class type to string, although the database type is integer. Thank you for both of your response.